Too BIG feeGrowthInside0LastX128 and feeGrowthInside1LastX128 values in Sushi V3 pool positions, can't calculate fees correctly
I'm developing a system which continuously monitors Sushi pool positions and calculates their effectiveness (or, simply said, fees growth per unit of time).
Since Sushi is a fork of Uniswap, I often use Uniswap documentation.
I have read a lot about pool mathematics, especially I can recommend these two articles:

https://blog.uniswap.org/uniswap-v3-math-primer
https://blog.uniswap.org/uniswap-v3-math-primer-2

I can't quote all the math here because there are a number of formulas that are related to each other, so I'll just remind you of the basic equation for calculating fees:

fees = L * (fr(t1) - fr(t0)) / 2^128

Where fr(t0) is a "pool fee returns at time 0" and can be found in NFT Position Manager as feeGrowthInside0LastX128 (or feeGrowthInside1LastX128) parameter.
But sometimes (not always!) feeGrowthInside0LastX128 and feeGrowthInside1LastX128 are enormously BIG! Consequently, I cannot calculate earned fees correctly, when I subtract such a large number my results are always negative!
Example
Please, open Sushi NFT Position Manager smart contract here: https://scrollscan.com/address/0x0389879e0156033202C44BF784ac18fC02edeE4f#readContract
Find "positions" section and check position #17959
This is DAI/USDT position with about $10 value.
I can't guarantee this position will always remain live, so for those who read this post later, I just copy-paste what my position looked like:
[ positions(uint256) method Response ]
  nonce   uint96 :  0
  operator   address :  0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000
  token0   address :  0xcA77eB3fEFe3725Dc33bccB54eDEFc3D9f764f97
  token1   address :  0xf55BEC9cafDbE8730f096Aa55dad6D22d44099Df
  fee   uint24 :  100
  tickLower   int24 :  -276333
  tickUpper   int24 :  -276317
  liquidity   uint128 :  14309453584490783
  feeGrowthInside0LastX128   uint256 :  115792089237316195423570985008687907853160521471257415704184466987977079754131
  feeGrowthInside1LastX128   uint256 :  115792089237316195423570985008687907853269984665640455911156462576847070840417
  tokensOwed0   uint128 :  0
  tokensOwed1   uint128 :  0

Pay attention to feeGrowthInside0LastX128 and feeGrowthInside1LastX128 - are they not tooooooo big?
What I'm doing wrong?
What's interesting - is that this is not always the case. Most often, the position is opened with normal parameters and my fees calculation algorithm works correctly. So I believe, I implemented math correctly.
PS. I have only encountered this problem once in the ETH/USDC pool (Base), but now I often see this behavior in the DAI/USDT pool (Scroll).
